# Typescript doesn't like "dialog" in ko.bindingHandlers.dialog statement

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I'm trying to get jqueryUI dialogues to work with a knockoutjs viewmodel and have tried this. Any ideas what is wrong with this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
```

Resulting in Error The property 'dialog' does not exist on value of type 'KnockoutBindingHandlers'

however, I have imported Knockout:

```
///<reference path="d.ts/knockout.d.ts"/>
```

Comment: You can try with `ko.bindingHandlers['dialog'] = {`

Answer (score 2):

I can't see that on the interface in the .d.ts file. You could extend it like this...

```
interface KnockoutBindingHandlers {
    dialog: {};
}
```

And you can fill in more details about the expected type for dialog to get static typing and intelliSense.